# When installing libbitcoin is there an option to deactivate the warnings?

Tags: raspberry-pi, libbitcoin

When installing `libbitcoin` from [here](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system#debianubuntu) with `$ ./install.sh --prefix=/home/me/myprefix --build-boost --disable-shared` after most of the compilation is done there are checks of the sourcecode with warnings like this one:

```
In file included from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/machine/operation.hpp:159:0,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/chain/script.hpp:31,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/chain/output.hpp:28,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/chain/output_point.hpp:25,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/chain/input.hpp:27,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/chain/transaction.hpp:30,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/chain/block.hpp:31,
                 from ./include/bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp:24,
                 from test/chain/transaction.cpp:20:
./include/bitcoin/bitcoin/impl/machine/operation.ipp:136:15: warning: ‘size_t libbitcoin::machine::variable_uint_size(uint64_t)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static size_t variable_uint_size(uint64_t value)
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I was under the impression that the compiling was already finished and this is something that comes afterwards. During this process, which took half a day, my Pi runs out of HDD swap (1,7GB) and crashes. Is there an option to deactivate those warnings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When installing libbitcoin there are checks of the code, why is this?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/when-installing-libbitcoin-there-are-checks-of-the-code-why-is-this)

Comment: I asked my question a second time because it is a different question, it is about deactivating.

Comment: The warnings are simply a byproduct of the compilation as I told you. You can disable the warnings but it won't make the compilation any faster. You need more memory to compile this code presumably.